# RoR controller method order affects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I've dealing with an issue for some days. The thing is that I had a controller with:

```
private 
def posts_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title,:shortDesc,:longDesc,:imgName)
end
def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end
```

Show method didn't work till I changed the order and I put the private method at the bottom.

Is there any ruby or rails issue related with?

I'm new in RoR

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all methods before *private* are private so they can't be call from another class. you can:

1. change methods order (what you do) or
2. put *public* before `def show` to change the scope.

Comment: Ok, so when you write private it affects all the methods above.